# Suppress Ribbon Menu Auto Expanding

Tags: javascript, ribbon

Working in a view for a Document Library I enabled "inline-editing" and discovered that as any input-element receives focus the *documents-ribbon-menu* auto expands. This behavior is undesirable so my goal is to prevent the menu from auto expanding.

Through debugging I discovered suppressing `window.SelectRibbonTab` prevents this.

To resolve I created "test.aspx" so that when it is the current page the execution of `window.SelectRibbonTab` is suppressed, but all other page instances will remain unaffected.
I attempted to pattern my override from these stack answers 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172505/how-to-override-the-window-open-functionality) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296667/overriding-a-javascript-function-while-referencing-the-original) but I'm unfamiliar with this concept and I am receiving a "Cannot assign to a function result" message.

Have a look at code below

```
window.SelectRibbonTab = function (obj) {
    if (location.pathname.search('test.aspx')=0) {
        return SelectRibbonTab.call(window, obj);
    };
}(window.SelectRibbonTab);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if (location.pathname.search('test.aspx') = 0) {
```

To this:

```
if (location.pathname.search('test.aspx') == 0) {
```

You are assigning zero to location.pathname.search('test.aspx'), not testing if it is zero.

Second part:

```
window.SelectRibbonTab = function (SelectRibbonTab) {
  return function ("Ribbon.Read", true) {
  if (location.pathname.search('test.aspx')==0) {
      return SelectRibbonTab.call(window, "Ribbon.Read", true);
  }
  };
}(window.SelectRibbonTab);
```

I think this should work...I don't have a way to test it unfortunately.

**FINAL**  Okay, so I finally figured it out :D

```
window.SelectRibbonTab = function (SelectRibbonTab) {
  return function (tabID, forced) {
  if (location.pathname.search('test.aspx')<0) {
      return SelectRibbonTab.call(window, tabID, forced);
  }
  };
}(window.SelectRibbonTab);
```

Now, when you run the the function in the actual code (window.SelectRibbonTab("Ribbon.document")) I think it should run the custom function that you wrote (I hope).

Comment: Thank you - that resolved the `Cannot assign to a function` message however now I am receiving a `SCRIPT5002: Function expected` message.

Comment: Go into Firefox, and use the debugger to find the issue.  It should tell you what is causing this error.  Most likely, it is caused by a naming error, or type error.

Comment: Actually, I know what is causing this.  I will write into my original answer to answer the second part

Comment: The idea behind this is that you are adding code onto the original function.  So you are saying windows.SelectRibbonTab is now equal to the function that returns a constructor function, defining what action should be occuring.

Comment: I ran _Second part:_ but received `Expected Identifier` message.  I see where you're headed though ...I think I'm making a mess of the Closure, the method signature is `function SelectRibbonTab(tabId, force)`  When watched `tabId="Ribbon.Document"` and `force is omitted` I can even execute `SelectRibbonTab('Ribbon.Document')` in the console causing the ribbon to auto-expand.  But I'm not clear on how the parameters and method signature are expressed in the Closure. Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: Ahh!  That's it then.  Okay, I will update my final answer, and that should be correct (hopefully).  I have never actually worked with this, so sorry for the mistakes!

Comment: Thank you! **FINAL** works perfectly! I had to correct my logic - changed `location.pathname.search('test.aspx')<0`